# В чем отличие пакетов androidx.appcompat.widget и anroidx.core.widget?

Tags: android, androidx

Таких пакетов в библиотеке androidx много, не могу понять что означают appcompat  или core и почему у обоих пакетов есть widget ?

Я понимаю androidx, как расширение для стандартной Андроид, которая помогает приложению запускаться на старых устройствах. Но вот в обычном пакете android нет класса core.

Comment: У `AndroidX` задача теперь более широкая: выкатывать новинки не дожидаясь обновления самой платформы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пакет `androidx.appcompat.widget` содержит многие (но не все) виджеты из старого `android.support.v7.widget`.

А пакет `androidx.core.widget` содержит виджеты (тоже не все) из старого `android.support.v4.widget`.

Наверное для простоты миграции. Тут есть полная таблица:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate